# AngularJS configure a child window (Directive not working)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

OK, I have a child window with its own app.js. First, is this the best way to handle child windows, separate out the logic?

The issue I have is that while the controller in the child works fine, the directive does not. I have the same directive defined in a separate module for the parent, and it works great.

child HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="evidentia-child">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>
    <title>Evidentia Claims Editor</title>
</head>
<body>   
    <div style='width:100%' data-ng-controller='miniEditorController'>
        <textarea data-ng-model='data.editorText'
                  data-on-keyup="handleKeyup"
                  style='height:4em;width:24.5em;'>{{data.editorText}}</textarea>
        <button type='button' style='float:right;margin-top:1.2em;' 
                data-ng-disabled='data.disabled'
                data-ng-click='sendClaim();'>
            <img src='img/add16x16.png' width='16'/></button>   
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jqueryui-1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/MiniEditorController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app-child.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app-child.js:

```
'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services
angular.module('evidentia-child', [])
.directive('onKeyup', function() {
    return function(scope, elm, attrs) {
        //Evaluate the variable that was passed
        //In this case we're just passing a variable that points
        //to a function we'll call each keyup
        var keyupFn = scope.$eval(attrs.onKeyup);
        elm.bind('keyup', function(evt) {
            //$apply makes sure that angular knows 
            //we're changing something
            scope.$apply(function() {
                keyupFn.call(scope, evt);
            });
        });
    };
})
.controller('miniEditorController', ['$scope', MiniEditorController]);
```

controller:

```
function MiniEditorController($scope) {
 $scope.data = {};
 $scope.data.disabled = true;

 $scope.sendClaim = function() {
    if ($scope.data.editorText.length > 0) {
        window.opener.scope.$broadcast('newclaim', $scope.data.editorText);
        $scope.data.editorText = '';
    }
};

$scope.handleKeyup = function($event) {
    if ($scope.data.editorText.length > 0) {
        $scope.data.disabled = false;
    } else {
        $scope.data.disabled = true;
    }

    if ($event.ctrlKey && $event.keyCode === 13) {
        $scope.sendClaim(id);
    }
};
```

}

Comment: I usually do stuff like this in a modal instead of a child window. Just keeps things neater to be in the same app.

Comment: Normally I agree 100%.  However this particular window needs to be able to float on top of other applications, like a Word Document or an image displayed on another tab.